# Error when unzipping file using .Net framework

Tags: c#

I'm getting this strange exception when using the standard .Net Zip library (`System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`) and unzipping an archive with multiple large files in it.

The Exception is:

> Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.**

Code is as easy as this:

```
        using (var zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\BigFile.ZIP"))
        {
            zip.ExtractToDirectory(@"C:\Temp");                   
        }
```

The zip file I'm trying to unzip is approx 400mb large and it has 2 TEXT files of 5.5Gb each in it (+ 3 other small sized files).

I get the Exception no matter how I turn the code around (I've tried `foreach` loop to extract files one by one and same problem).

Now what is really strange is that the extract works perfectly fine on my dev machine (from VS or not). 
However, I'm getting this exception as soon as I'm trying it on a server. 
The server machine has .NET 4.5 installed, it's primary function is a SQL server so it has few things running on it but it has plenty of resources, it's a Windows server 2008 R2 x64 with plenty of Memory (32GB) and CPU.

Let's go deeper into the strangeness...
If I modify the Zip file so that there are only 1 of the 2 big files remaining, it works fine (on the server). I thought somehow I was hitting a limit due to the file size but clearly not the case with this scenario.

Obviously, any other archive with smaller files works perfectly fine with the above code.

Any ideas what is going on there?

Just to give some background before everyone starts bombarding with "use 3rd party etc..." I am working on a C# Script run in a DTS package from SSIS and working with 3rd parties in those is not possible for all I know.

Thanks

Comment: On your Dev Env you run it as part of SSIS package? If yes than what is your add SQL server data of your Dev Env

Comment: Sorry I should have specified this, I'm getting this error in a minimal console application so outside of SSIS.

Comment: Is that console app will work on server?

Comment: The console app is literally 6 lines of code only for testing/reproducing the error. So No it doesn't work on the server (but only when the zip file contains 2 very large text files, it works fine when it has only 1 text file).

Comment: Zip file size will change depending on the server and file system you are using.  You are unzipping the file from the c drive so it is obvious you copied the file from the working machine to your current machine.  So I'm wondering if the file got corrupted or changed when the copy was performed.  I would try unzipping it with the windows unzip manually and see if it works.

Comment: Good point and yes it works, on both environment, the archive is tested and re-tested and 100% valid, yet while unzipping from code I'm getting that exception.

Comment: I am going to give up and use 7zip through command lines called from C# but I'm not big fan of this solution.